# How to handle MIME type in tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

I am new to Tornado framework. When I set the header type `application/pdf`, But it takes only default MIME Type i.e; `plian/text`. Here my code,

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            ifile = open("requirements.txt", "r")
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf; charset="utf-8"')
            self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"')
            #print(self.list_headers())
            self.write(ifile.read())
```

It is downloading successfully through web browser. Here url http:/203.193.173.102:8888/.
But when I open the pdf file it is not opened. Any one help me. Thanks

Comment: Why do you open `requirement.txt` instead of `test.pdf`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't know how to read pdf file in tornado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        with open('test.pdf', 'rb') as f:  
            self.set_header("Content-Type", 'application/pdf; charset="utf-8"')
            self.set_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf")                  
            self.write(f.read())
```

Comment: I am tried this. But it gives the error --> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 10: invalid start byte

Comment: @dhana could you try to replace `open('test.pdf', 'r')` with `codecs.open('test.pdf', 'r', 'utf-8')`? (also, don't forget to `import codecs`).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried as you said. But it gives the --> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 10: invalid start byte. Please solve my problem.